# Call .toDouble on Any and return Option[Double]

Tags: scala

Curious if anyone has a creative approach for the following:

```
def toDouble(any: Any): Option[Double] = // { if any has a .toDouble method call it else return None }
```

For instance, Int, String, Long all have a .toDouble method. I'd like it to be called if it exist (even non primitive types).

Ideally something like this (without .toString'ing everything first)

```
def toDouble(any: Any): Option[Double] = {
  case any.hasToDouble => Try(any.toDouble).toOption
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Should probably have a look at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html

Comment: Other types (notably String) may have a .toDouble method as well

Comment: @user451151 String does not have a toDouble. The method is provided via implicits which can only be resolved at compile time.  Without a compile-time type you will need to use reflection.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
def doubleFromAny(in: Any): Option[Double] = {
  Try{in.asInstanceOf[{def toDouble: Double}].toDouble}.toOption
}
```

The problem with this is any `toDouble` provided through an implicit won't work (so the string `"4.5"` would give you `None`).  I also expect performance would not be great.

In the end, you need to figure out what types are possible and use something like Jon Anderson's answer to check and cast each type.

Comment: Isn't structural typing ultimately implemented via reflection?  If he is worried about using `.toString` on a billion objects, reflection might have a similar performance concern.

Comment: @JonAnderson Yes I could see performance being a problem with this.  Even leaving aside the structural typing concerns, unless almost all of the inputs have a toDouble method there will be lots of exception throwing/catching. Ultimately, I don't think there is any good solution to this problem in Scala.  If this functionality is required go with a dynamic language.  I think your solution is the way to go, but thought I might provide an alternative.  Each answer here has different pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pattern matching.  This has the additional benefit of giving you more explicit control over how the conversion is done.  (Eg, if you wanted to try additional string parsing)

```
def toDouble(any: Any): Option[Double] = {
  any match {
    case n:Int => Some(n.toDouble)
    case n:Long => Some(n.toDouble)
    case n:Double => Some(n.toDouble)
    case s:String => Try(s.toDouble).toOption
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this as well, but the thought of taking `Any` just to pattern match on types is just crippling.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm currently doing. The issue is maintenance: some custom objects are being passed that have a .toDouble, which requires me to keep manually adding a case for them :P. Was hoping I could programmatically check for a .toDouble and then try to call it.

Comment: This validates that I'm not crazy! Thank you.

Comment: @user451151 If you are working with custom objects then you will probably want to make a `HasToDouble` trait which your objects will extend

Answer (score 1):

```
  def toDouble(a: Any): Option[Double] = try {
    if (a == null) None else {
      Some(a.toString.toDouble)
    }
  } catch {
    case scala.util.control.NonFatal(e) => None
  }
```

Comment: Any way of doing it without .toString ing everything? I'll be running this on billions of records; would love to avoid the toString if possible.

Comment: Working with `Any` is a hint of code smell/bad design

Comment: Agreed,  but sometimes (when the type passed to you is out of your control) there's not a great way around it. (If you have suggestions, I'm all ears!)

Answer (score -1):

Others have suggested good answers. Another way I thought of doing was using implicit object. For your above example you could write something like:

```
sealed trait ImplicitType[T]
object ImplicitType{
  implicit object IntType extends ImplicitType[Int]
  implicit object StringType extends ImplicitType[String]
  implicit object LongType extends ImplicitType[Long]
  implicit object DoubleType extends ImplicitType[Double]
}

def toDouble[T : ImplicitType](n: T) : Option[Double] = {
  Try(n.toString.toDouble).toOption
}
```

The above works because, the compiler constraint is from the availability of implicit objects in `ImplicitType` companion object. The context bound implicit def f: ImplicitType[T] by default searches for implicit objects inside companion object of `ImplicitType`. So now you can do things like:

```
val foo = toDouble(1) // Some(1.0)
val foo1 = toDouble("2") //Some(2.0)
val foo2 = toDouble(1L) //Some(1.0)
val foo3 = toDouble("s") //None
val foo4 = toDouble(1.23456e300d) //Some(1.23456E300)
```

In this way your `toDouble` function does not change at all. I couldn't think of a way to avoid `toString` sorry. Hope this works for you.

Comment: This only works if you know the  type ahead of time.  OP is working with `Any`.  If you are doing this you also should implement `toDouble` in implicit type to avoid overhead from toString and exceptions.  As is is your solution is essentially equivalent to radumanolescu's answer but restricts the type of the function instead of accepting `Any`.